# BOOL property from a calculation returns NSNumber with incorect value using valueForKey:

Tags: ios, objective-c, kvc

I have a simple object which has one NSNumber which is used to store some flags. 
I have a conienience getter method which in fact does:

```
[self.flags integerValue] & SomeConstantFlag
```

for a property`@property (readonly, nonatomic, assign) BOOL someConstantFlag`

and this works fine when accesing the underlying bool value like

```
model.someConstantFlag
```

but when I try to

```
id value = [model valueForKey:@"someConstantFlag"];
```

Then it returns a bad boolean representation e.g. NSNumber with value 2, 4 etc.
Why is this happening when the declaration of the property is BOOL? Is there a "Pretty" way to overcome this issue?

Wrapping on the other hand works ok:

```
BOOL someBool = 42;
NSNumber* numberVal = @(someBool);
//The underlying is an __NSCFBoolean with the proper 0/1 val!
```

Comment: Try `BOOL someBool = [model boolForKey:@"someConstantFlag"];`

Comment: May be this is because of `id` type ? BOOL is not an `id`..btw, both 2 and 4 is actually `YES`

Comment: This is not the case as I am using a generic method of handling creation of XML => i just send some properties and their coresponding names so that I can create the XML dynamically (the object-> to XML part). So I want to do this without any "type knowledge".

The problem arises with the valueForKey: boxing -> the suggar code boxing works ok @(someBool).

Comment: `id` is a pointer to an object. but BOOL is not an object.

Comment: I made a "not so pretty" overcoming of this by making a definition
`#define KVCCompilantBoolFromNumber(a) ((a) ? (1) : (0))` i Need this because I just create the inner string value from the id object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valueForKey` always returns an Objective-C object, even if the property has scalar type.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html) (emphasis mine):

> The default implementations of `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:`
>   provide support for automatic object wrapping of the non-object data
>   types, both scalars and structs.
>
> Once `valueForKey:` has determined the specific accessor method or
>   instance variable that is used to supply the value for the specified
>   key, it examines the return type or the data type. If the value to be
>   returned is not an object, **an `NSNumber` or `NSValue` object is created**
>   for that value and returned in its place.

The return value of your method is `BOOL`, which is defined as

```
typedef signed char BOOL;
```

on OS X and on the 32-bit iOS platform. So what `valueForKey` returns is a `NSNumber`
containing the result of

```
signed char val = [self.flags integerValue] & SomeConstantFlag;
```

and that can be in the range -128 .. 127.

To ensure that you get only `YES` or `NO` (aka 1 or 0) write your custom getter as:

```
-(BOOL)someConstantFlag
{
    return ([self.flags integerValue] & SomeConstantFlag) != 0;
}
```

*Remark:* On the 64-bit iOS platform (but not on 64-bit OS X), `BOOL` is defined as the C99 `_Bool`, which is a "proper" boolean type and can take only the value 0 or 1.

Comment: Problem with this is as before mentioned that the simple BOXING works and the `valueForKey:` does not work -> Does this mean that using `@(someBool)` is other that the `valueForKey:` (`@(someBool)` knows the type and uses the `__NSCFBoolean`?)?. Casting to BOOL when returning the value from the property accessor does not help!

Comment: @okipol: The compiler translates `@(someBool)` to `[NSNumber numberWithBool:…]`, that's why it works. The Key-Value Coding wrapper is not so smart. - Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Returning a value other than 0 or 1 from a method declared as BOOL is considered a serious bug by most people, with the expectation that eventually it will catch up with you and bite you in the arse. As it did. Martin's suggestion is a perfectly fine solution to your problem which you should accept instead of insisting on using buggy code.

Comment: Well now in the updated post I see the awnser ;). Many Thanks! Please do LookUp my comment from some time ago attached to the main question for using 

`#define KVCCompilantBoolFromNumber(a) ((a) ? (1) : (0))`

Which I thinnk is more reusable (reuse in manny getters) and acomplishes the same doesn't it? Thx for describing the difference betwen the sugar boxing and valueForKey.

Comment: @okipol: You are welcome! - `(a) != 0` is exactly equivalent to `((a) ? (1) : (0))`, so you can choose whatever you like more. - Btw, your "problem" does not occur on 64-bit iOS, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumber *value = @([model objectForKey:@"someConstantFlag"]);

BOOL boolVal = [value boolValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider the following problems. Firstly, integerValue returns NSInteger which means if you support 64Bit architecture it will return int_64 not int_32, what is more in your code here

```
    [self.flags integerValue] & SomeConstantFlag
```

this does the following if flags is 00010  and somConstantFlags is 00001 the & of those will do something you probably does not expect because you will get value of 00000 which equals 0 or if they are  00011 and 00110 you will get 00010 which equals 2. So that is why when you call valueForKey you get 2 or 4 or something else depending on your flags :)
What is more in objective-C everything different then 0 is YES.

Try reconsidering your bit logic :). See The following example

```
    enum 
    {
    kWhite   = 0,
    kBlue    = 1 << 0,
    kRed     = 1 << 1,
    kYellow  = 1 << 2,
    kBrown   = 1 << 3,
    };
    typedef char ColorType;
```

and in your setter check the following

```
ColorType pinkColor = kWhite | kRed;
if (pinkColor & (kWhite | kBlue | kRed | kYellow)) {
// any of the flags has been set
}
```

The flags kWhite, kBlue, kRed and kYellow have been set.

However, kBrown has not been set.

Comment: Thx for the anwser. But the logic I have is what I want -> In Your example when I get `0` then my property says that the flag is not set and when i get `2` then the property says that the specific flag is set. I use `flags` to store all of the flags in SQL lite DB -> one entry not nFlag entries. The only problem i am having is that even though the property is `BOOL` I get a wraped value as You have described (e.g. 2) but I want it to be 1 or 0 just like the @() would wrap it.

Comment: try [[model valueForKey:@"someConstantFlag"] boolValue]